# How to retrieve a session value from Javascript in another aspx.cs page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have used a session in Javascript as below.

```
var myvar = "Welcome"; '<%Session["Test"] = "' + myvar +'"; %>';
```

How to retrieve that session value in another aspx.cs page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using single quotes around the set session command ?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve??

Answer (score 1):

Update the session value in hidden field in your JavaScript code.

And get the value from hidden value on the server side and update the session value.

Comment: How to update ? i really appreciate if you would help me out... Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var jsVar = '<%= Session["Test"].ToString() %>';
```

C#

```
string csVar = Session["Test"].ToString();
```

Comment: Hi.. i want to retrieve that value in code behind file , but not in aspx page

Comment: check my updated post. however, i am not sure about your code. why do you need single quotes around '<%Session["Test"] = "' + myvar +'"; %>' ; ???

Comment: Actually JavaScript code i have written to display google map in another pop-up window. In that case your suggestion for using session without single quotes does not works. Thats why i putted like that. Moreover, by using this -  string csVar = Session["Test"].ToString(); as you suggested, their, i am not retrieving session value.. instead retrieving simply  ' + myvar +'

Comment: The .ToString() will fail (NullReferenceException) when that value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

U think this may help you

```
var Session = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"]';
```